# Anime with a character that changes genders when he/she touches water?

Tags: ranma

I saw it once on TV and the only thing I can remember is someone changing genders when he/she was dumped in water (presumably hot).

Can anyone match up these details to an anime series that might have this?

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide some more info - when you saw it, what the main character looked like, etc?

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko like i said this is the only thing i remember i didn't get a good look at the main character and im not even sure if that was the main character

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like Ranma 1/2 - The main character changes gender when they get splashed or come in contact with water

[image]

> Ranma Saotome and his father, Genma, both practitioners of the Saotome school of anything-goes martial arts, fall into the cursed springs of the legendary training ground of Jusenkyo in mainland China during a training mission. Each spring holds a different curse for any who come in contact with its water, all of which involve who or what has drowned in the spring in the past - Ranma emerges from the spring a girl and Genma a panda, both now cursed to change forms each time they come in contact with hot and cold water.
>   [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/210/Ranma_%C2%BD)

Comment: Hot water change them to their original state while cold water change them to "curse" state

Comment: could be this one but are there any others and the character changing genders doesn't have to be the main character

Comment: @NoLifeKing You should try watching something about the anime in hand, to see if it triggers your visual memory. IF you are asking for a list of gender-changing-in-water anime, then...